# Why express different modal logics in set theoretic terms?

Tags: logic, modal-logic

On pg. 31 of Girle's Modal Logics and Philosophy he starts describing various modal logics in set theoretic notation, where the sets denoted are referencing truth-tree formation rules in the context of the semantic tableaux method he uses in the text.

For example to describe S4 he (apparently following Hintikka) writes the following:

$HS4Tr = SW \cup \{\Diamond R,\Box R, \Box T, \Box\Box R\}$

So, I understand the set-theoretic backdrop of the possible worlds semantics for modal logics. But this seems to be a set-theoretic backdrop for tree-formation rules, i.e. a syntactic topic. So what exactly are these sets sets of? Possible worlds too somehow? Well formed strings of symbols whose graphic construction sequences the rules represent?

Thanks so much for any insight!

Comment: Not very clear... "set language" is used to describe mathematical objects and structures, like trees, etc.

Comment: "So what exactly are these sets sets of? (referring to trees)" See [Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)): "In graph theory, a tree is an undirected graph in which any two vertices are connected by exactly one path, " and a [Grtaph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)#Undirected_graph) is "a pair G = (V, E), where V is a set whose elements are called vertices (singular: vertex), and E is a set of paired vertices, whose elements are called edges "

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA So these sets are sets of vertices--namely, the sets of vertices that conform to the construction rules? And is it right to think of trees as syntactic objects?

Comment: No, a tree is not a "syntactic objects". Syntactic objects are: symbols, expressions, formulas, sequences of formulas. A tree is a mathematical structure that we **use** to describe the syntax, like numbers are mathematical objects that we **use** to manage syntax.

Comment: In general, a "model/interpretation" for a logic is a mathematical structure; thus, we use mathematical language (set-based) to describe it.

Comment: In the same way, the rigorous specification of syntax is made using mathematical (set-based) language, like e.g. the specifications for a computer compiler.